# TypeError: state.customerComplaints.add is not a function in jest unit test

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuex

I have a simple mutation method where I add elements to my Set. Now I am trying to test that method and jest is throwing an error as mentioned below.

```js
//Vuex
const state = {
  customerComplaints : new Set()
};

// Mutation method
setCustomerComplaints(state, data) {
  state.customerComplaints.add(data);
}

//Error I am getting when running the test
//TypeError: state.customerComplaints.add is not a function

//Jest test
it('should do something', () => {
  const state = {
    customerComplaints: {}
  };
  myStore.mutations.setCustomerComplaints(state, 'UI issue');
  expect(state.customerComplaints).toBe('UI issue');
});
```

I tried to mock it but I am unable to succeed in it. Please help me in passing this test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test has a local `state` object that doesn't contain an `add` method, and it's passing that `state` to the mutation method that tries to call `add`, leading to the error you observed.

A simple fix is to initialize your local `state.customerComplaints` to a `Set`, just like you do in your actual Vuex store:

```js
it('should do something', () => {
  const state = {
    customerComplaints: new Set()
  };
  myStore.mutations.setCustomerComplaints(state, 'UI issue');
  //...
});
```

Also, to verify that a `Set` contains an item, use [`toContain`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tocontainitem), not `toBe`:

```js
// expect(state.customerComplaints).toBe('UI issue');
expect(state.customerComplaints).toContain('UI issue');
```